# How to sum currency items of an array

Tags: ios, sum, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I want to sum items of an array. These items are currency. However, it has problem when parse to NSNumber from String. Please see my code below

```
NSString *cash;
cash = self.textfield.text; // textfield has format: currencyFormatter

NSNumberFormatter * number = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
[number setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [number numberFromString:cash]; // convert into number from string
NSLog(@"myNumber:%@",myNumber);

NSMutableArray *tmp_cash;
[tmp_cash addObject:myNumber]; // add object to Array
long long sum = ((NSNumber*)[tmp_cash valueForKeyPath:  @"@sum.longLongValue"]).longLongValue; // sum items of array
```

However, app crashes and show log `myNumber` is `null`. Please help me fix this bug

Comment: When you say "_textfield has format_" do you mean that `cash` is not just a plan number, or that you have a formatter for it? Can you give an example of what `cash` could be?

Comment: ex: I enter data from keyboard: 200, textfield will show $2.00. And cash is 2.00 because i use :cash = [cash substringFromIndex:1]; to remove first character. Sr for my bad english

Comment: What cash has after cash = self.textfield.text;? Take a breakpoint and look what inside.

Comment: @user3525058 use that same `currencyFormatter` you use to display the number, to read it back in as a `NSNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `currencyFormatter` you used to display the number in the `textField`. Change `currencyFormatter` to be a property, and lazily load it, to make sure its always initialized:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter;

-(NSNumberFormatter *)currencyFormatter
{
    if (!_currencyFormatter) {
        _currencyFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
        // set up other options
    }
    return _currencyFormatter;
}
```

Now you can use that to parse the text in the `UITextField`:

```
NSString *cash;
cash = self.textfield.text; // textfield has format: currencyFormatter

NSNumber * myNumber = [self.currencyFormatter numberFromString:cash]; // convert into number from string
NSLog(@"myNumber:%@",myNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks Rich. But it does not still work. It still show myNumber is null

Comment: @duyklinsi as previously asked can you update your answer with the `NSLog` output of `cash` :) But before you do anything to it. And also please add the code for creating your `currencyFormatter` too!

Comment: I added the code for currencyFormatter. This is my log:2014-04-27 18:39:06.574 MoneyManagement[1696:c07] cash:222,255.55
2014-04-27 18:39:06.575 MyProject[1696:c07] myNumber:(null)
2014-04-27 18:39:06.576 MyProject[1696:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: @duyklinsi I don't see any more code? And what does the following output `NSLog(@"CASH: %@", self.textfield.text);`, if you put that directly after `cash = self.textfield.text;`

Comment: I have tried to change [number setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle]; to             [number setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
. It works. However myNumber is 222255.55 although the value of Cash is 222,255.55

Comment: As I shown above. This is Nslog for Cash: 2014-04-27 18:39:06.574 MyProject[1696:c07] cash:222,255.55

Comment: The group separators (the `,`s) are for display purposes only, `NSNumber` doesn't care about them